# How to dig a hole for a specific screw?

Tags: screws

Yesterday I combined pieces of furniture into a whole desk.

But how are the holes in furniture dug in the first place?

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you're referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you referring to a *pilot hole*? You can use a drill and a drill bit that is slightly smaller than the bore of the screw and create a hole for the screw to use. The screw will still bite into the wood, but won't displace as much material, and the screw will follow the hole for a straighter drive. Using a *pilot hole* will reduce the chances of cracking the wood and mis-driving the screw.

Comment: And in some case, the holes might be counter-bored or countersunk, depending on what type of screws you're using.